# Django 1.11 showing Warnings message

Tags: python, django, warnings, deprecation-warning

When I'm running a Django test server locally with `./manage.py runserver`, lots of warnings are showing up (DeprecationWarning, RemovedInDjango20Warning), even if they shouldn't be there by default (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/1.11/#deprecating-warnings-are-no-longer-loud-by-default).

I've put this code in a Django command :

```py
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter("ignore", DeprecationWarning)
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", RemovedInDjango20Warning)
```

and it's hiding the warnings on that command, but I don't know where to put it so that it hide all warnings globally (I've tried in manage.py, settings.py, models.py,...)

I've also tried to run `python -W ignore manage.py runserver` which is supposed to tell python not to show warnings, but it still display all warnings.

Warnings look like that :

```
/.../venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/review/templatetags/review_tags.py:11: RemovedInDjango20Warning: assignment_tag() is deprecated. Use simple_tag() instead @register.assignment_tag
```

or

```
/.../models/results.py: RemovedInDjango20Warning: on_delete will be a required arg for ForeignKey in Django 2.0. Set it to models.CASCADE on models and in existing migrations if you want to maintain the current default behavior
```

One possibility would be to update Django version and make all change suggested by warnings but it would be too long and I just want to hide those warnings.

Comment: Try with [silenced system checks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#silenced-system-checks).

Comment: Thanks @ipaleka but I'm afraid the warnings are not coming from Django, but from Python itself :/